# Python Selenium Click a button with class

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-webdriver, css-selectors, selenium-chromedriver

I'm new to python selenium and I'm trying to click on a button which has the following HTML structure:

```
<div class="wpsafe-top text-center"> 
  <h1><strong><span style="color: #ce2525;">Click on Submit to Get Link</span></strong></h1><br>
  <form action="https://url.com/post" method="post">
    <input type="hidden" name="getlink" value="NVudM3E">
    <input type="hidden" name="newwpsafelink" value="eyJsaW5rIjoiTlZ1ZE0zRSIsImFkczEiOiIiLCJhZHMyIjoiIiwibG9nbyI6IiIsImltYWdlMSI6Imh0dHA6XC9cL3RlY2hjb2RlY3MuY29tXC93cC1jb250ZW50XC91cGxvYWRzXC8yMDE5XC8xMlwvZ2VuLnBuZyIsImltYWdlMiI6Imh0dHA6XC9cL3RlY2hjb2RlY3MuY29tXC93cC1jb250ZW50XC91cGxvYWRzXC8yMDE5XC8xMlwvcGx6LnBuZyIsImltYWdlMyI6Imh0dHA6XC9cL3RlY2hjb2RlY3MuY29tXC93cC1jb250ZW50XC91cGxvYWRzXC8yMDE5XC8xMlwvY2xrLnBuZyIsImxpbmtyIjoiaHR0cHM6XC9cL3RlY2hjb2RlY3MuY29tP3NhZmVsaW5rX3JlZGlyZWN0PTUlNUIlOUQzcSIsImRlbGF5dGV4dCI6IjxiPjxoMiBzdHlsZT0nY29sb3I6cmVkJz5Mb2FkaW5nIExpbmsgLi4uIFdhaXQgPHNwYW4gaWQ9XCJ3cHNhZmUtdGltZVwiPjEyPFwvc3Bhbj4gU2Vjb25kczxcL2gyPjxcL2I+IiwiZGVsYXkiOiIxMiIsImFkYiI6IjIiLCJhZGIxIjoiIiwiYWRiMiI6IiJ9">
    <input class="btn btn-primary" type="submit" value="Submit">
  </form> 
</div>
```

I have tried this to click on Submit Button.

`driver.find_element_by_css_selector('btn btn-primary').click()`

But i always end up with error

```
Message: no such element: Unable to locate element: {"method":"css selector","selector":".btn btn-primary"}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`find_element_by_css_selector('btn btn-primary')` will look fir an element with tag `btn-primary` that has ancestor element with tag `btn`.

You need to tell the `driver` those are classes with `.`

```
driver.find_element_by_css_selector('.btn.btn-primary').click()
```

Or explicitly

```
driver.find_element_by_css_selector('[class="btn btn-primary"]').click()
```